# Housing in Amsterdam

Tags: netherlands, accommodation, housing

This question is about semi-permanent housing in Amsterdam (no hotels, hostels, guest rooms, etc).

1. What are the local resources for finding housing in Amsterdam? (websites, lists, groups, agencies?)
2. What should one look out for in order to avoid touristic traps?
3. Which are the cheapest options and how are they browsable and/or reachable (same as #1 but with a price criterion)?
4. How can one browse housing in a specific area?

Comment: Welcome! As per the [help] and SE general guidelines, more than one question per post gets way too many answers.  It'd be better if you can edit it down, or split it up.  We're being extra strict as expats is still in beta :/ Thanks!

Comment: Couple of tourist traps: get an OV-card for the public transport system; and an Albert Heijn Bonus Card, for instant savings on food from AH. Both are free.

Comment: Common trap: **Rental scams**. People supposedly offering apartments, but not actually owning them or allowing you access to them - they just want to get a first advance on the first months' rent, and then they disappear.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a flat about two years ago. In general, it is difficult, if you are not speaking Dutch. Most apartments in the inner city are under strict rent control/social housing regulations, that means that you cannot rent an apartment without a ten-year (no joke) application process. I would look at the following places:

- [funda.nl](http://www.funda.nl)
- [Housing in Amsterdam on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/housinginamsterdam/)
- [Marktplaats.nl](http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/huizen-en-kamers/huizen-te-huur.html?categoryId=2143)
- [Craigslist Amsterdam](http://amsterdam.craigslist.org/search/apa) Beware of scammers here, don't send anyone money without seeing the apartment in person!